# Replace the content of a div several times

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have a select with my servers and I load information on the selected server without reloading the page. I am using ajax and ReplaceWith().

I tried using live() to replace the information several times, but it only works once, why?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select').live('change', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "server.php",
                data: "hostname=" + $(this).val(),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#results").replaceWith(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is data in your replaceWith call?

Comment: html. I found the solution: html() to place ReplaceWith(), it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are **replacing** the #results container with the data. The next time the $("#results") selector will not match any elements (because the container was replaced by the previous call).

.html() does not replace the container, but updates the content of the container.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand why it works with html() and not with ReplaceWith(), but it works!

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select').live('change', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "serveur.php",
                data: "hostname=" + $(this).val(),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#results").html(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sorry to answer my own question.

Comment: Because html() replaces the contents of the element, while replaceWith() replaces the actual element, so probably you replaced the element and the second time it didn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

live() method is kind of deprecated and might work not properly. Try on() instead of.

Comment: That's only if he uses jQuery 1.7